# Joomla Extended User info/registration from existing database

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I need to store several values after a user registration into user account. jos_users table from a second that resides on an external db.

So far only the name , email, username are stored , I am just reading the password to authenticate against this other db

What is the process joomla stores this information and how could store aditional values at registration into user account.

My plan is once they authenticate the first time, some fileds are copied from mssql and inserted into the user account jos_users table.,,,

So far I am able to connect to the external db and authenticate agains two columns , but dont know what to do next to pull the needed data..

/////Installing CB or JomSocial mis not an option 
Other Idea I have , is to hack the CB_ mysqlfield and make my MSSQL field.. Please Help

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have here, I would simply use Chronoforms. Here's what I would do -

1. Install v3.2.0, I would not use the v4.x version at this time, it does not seem like it has all the functionality yet.
2. Create form that captures all of the info needed for your additional table as well as Joomla registration.
3. Connect the form to the additional database table, this will store the extra fields you need.
4. Enable the Joomla registration plugin and map the fields to the corresponding Joomla required fields. This will store the info in the jos_users table.

There is a nice step by step of creating a registration form in Chronoforms here - http://www.navigatetomorrow.com/pdfs/Chronoforms_how_to_build_registration_page.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but preferbly I would like to avoid any registration at all and just insert this data from the MSSQl database directly , if this is not possible, then meabe a intermediate page which will post and read this data then log in the useR? Can you please advise?

Comment: I missed the MSSQL part, that changes everything. The info is already in MSSQL?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just trying to save the employeeid to match to my  mssql db to a variable, then retrieve some other mssql values using that ID...

Comment: any clue? I think onAfterStoreUser is the way to go justg need some help on code..